# Группировать checkbox-ы vue-js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Я только знакомлюсь с возможностями  javascript и VUE JS. Подскажите, как могу реализовать такой функционал: есть массив чекбоксов со значениями. При клике на определенный чекбокс, например, на чекбокс со значением item2, нужно сделать disabled всех значений  кроме текущего item2, а также item4 и item5, то есть, эти три мы можем отмечать чекбоксами.
Или, к примеру, если отмечен (первым элементом) item4, то делать disabled для всех значений, кроме текущего item4, а также item6, item1. Таких условий может быть несколько разных (до 3 случаев), но они все равно будут конкретными и неизменными. Как можно реализовать мою идею?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedItems: [],
    items: [{
        value: 'item1', id: 0
      },
      {
        value: 'item2', id: 1
      },
      {
        value: 'item3', id: 2
      },
      {
        value: 'item4', id: 3
      },
      {
        value: 'item5', id: 4
      },
      {
        value: 'item6', id: 5
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="flex items-center" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mr-2"
            :value="item.value"
            v-model="checkedItems" />
    <span>{{ item.value }}</span>
  </div>
  <span>{{checkedItems}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понятно что сделать то нужно, код ваш работает

Comment: Вы всё равно должны указывать в каждом элементе по какому критерию группировать, программе не важно животное или мотоцикл, это всего лишь стринг определённой длины и всё. Добавьте каждому элементу id_group например еще, далее отслеживайте на change изменение чекбокса и записывайте отмеченный в переменную. и в верстке будет потом так проверка: :disabled="item.id_group !== selectedGroup"

Comment: @DmitriiSedov понял, спасибо!

Comment: Если не получится приведу пример в ответе

Comment: @DmitriiSedov отредактировал вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При клике на чекбокс, по ключу child будет происходить проверка, на то какие элементы надо оставить включенными. И так же проверка на то, что элемент кликнут первым Например:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedItem: null,
    checkedItems: [],
    items: [{
        value: 'item1', id: 0, child: [2, 4],
      },
      {
        value: 'item2', id: 1, child: [5],
      },
      {
        value: 'item3', id: 2, child: [3],
      },
      {
        value: 'item4', id: 3, child: [1],
      },
      {
        value: 'item5', id: 4, child: [0, 3],
      },
      {
        value: 'item6', id: 5, child: [1, 3],
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    selectItem(item) {
      if (this.checkedItems.length) {
        if (this.selectedItem) return;
        this.selectedItem = item
      }
      else {
        this.selectedItem = null;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  height: 300px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="flex items-center" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mr-2"
            :value="item.value"
            v-model="checkedItems" 
            :disabled="selectedItem && !selectedItem.child.includes(item.id) && selectedItem.id !== item.id"
            @change="selectItem(item)"
    />
    <span>{{ item.value }}</span>
  </div>
  <span>{{selectedItem}}</span>
</div>
```

В результате кликая на нужный чекбокс, для дальнейшего выделения будут доступны лишь те которые подходят.

Comment: это решит проблему только в том случае, если у меня не будет повторов. К примеру, если мне нужно блокировать все, кроме item5 и item6, когда выделен item1. И блокировать только item6, когда выделен item2, допустим

Comment: @ИванШмелев Дополнил ответ. При клике на чекбокс, по ключу child будет происходить проверка, на то какие элементы надо оставить включенными. И так же проверка на то, что элемент кликнут первым.

Comment: @ИванШмелев то есть при клике на элемент item1 будут доступны item3 и item4, а при клике на item4 будет доступен только item2

Comment: да, все верно поняли

Comment: @ИванШмелев Отмечайте ответ галочкой (слева под стрелками) если он Вам помог, чтобы он индексировался и другие пользователи с похожей проблемой могли найти решение